# How to permit debugging on dependency AS2 SWF files?

Tags: flash, debugging, flash-cs3, actionscript-2

I have a SWF that I wish to debug on with the flash debugger. I have the debug flash player and the 'Debugger' context menu option is greyed out. If I check the 'Permit debugging' option in the SWF publish settings, this does not become enabled.

My hunch is that this is down to the fact that my SWF is being loaded by another parent SWF. Before I embark on a potentially large job to republish this parent SWF, I wanted to guage whether it was worth it by determining:

- Am I right? Does the parent SWF also need debugging permitted?
- Is it only the parent SWF? Or do all SWFs in the scene need to be published with the same settings, no matter where they appear in relation to the target debug SWF?
- Are there any other reasons for the debugger option being unavailable to me in my movie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question...

From tests - Only parent SWFs need debugging enabled. Siblings irrelevant to debugging don't need it enabled.